# Is it possible to validate only password for AWS Cognito user with MFA enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I have a scenario that requires extra password validation for mission critical parts of an application. i.e. when user performs very sensitive action ze should enter the password in order to confirm the action.

I've tried `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` and it would work for users with no `MFA` enabled. But when `SMS_MFA` is enabled for a user, even though I validated a password, SMS message is sent. SMS message with no reason confuses user.

Is there a way to skip `SMS_MFA` for some cases?

Comment: Struggling with the same problem... Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: Me too. Any new solutions?

Comment: So far (per support) it seems to be impossible.

Comment: Any update with this? I also require this functionality. Did AWS update this?